# Plotting multiple subplots on multiple plots in qqplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that has a timeseries data for different countries and different variables. Let us say there are two countries (UK, US) and two variables (GMS, PP) - for each country, I want to plot two timeseries one against the other one for each variable.

Meaning I want to have 2 plots with 2 subplots, i.e. UK will have two plots where I have a timeseries for GMS and PP (same for the US).

I also want to add a legend to the plots.

```
       month marketplace value_fcst_1 value_fcst_2 variable
1 2019-05-26          US      4202393      4198816      GMS
2 2019-06-02          US     30504725     31525980      GMS
3 2019-06-09          US     30454694     30602385      GMS
4 2019-06-16          US     30249561     30363117      ALC
5 2019-06-23          US     30884821     31682497      ALC
6 2019-06-30          US     31424970     31198360      ALC
7 2019-05-26          UK      4202393      4198816      GMS
8 2019-06-02          UK     30504725     31525980      GMS
9 2019-06-09          UK     30454694     30602385      GMS
10 2019-06-16         UK     30249561     30363117      ALC
11 2019-06-23         UK     30884821     31682497      ALC
12 2019-06-30         UK     31424970     31198360      ALC
```

I managed to plot all of variables but not sure how to divide graphs for US and UK and how to adjust y-axis for each variable as the scale does not match (see photo).

```
series_plot <- ggplot(data = final_df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = value_fcst_1), colour = 'dodgerblue2', na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = value_fcst_2), colour = 'coral2', na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(vars(variable)) +
  labs(x = 'Months') +
  labs(title = 'Comparisons of two different forecast runs', subtitle = '2019-05-31 vs 2019-06-30 forecast runs') 
  # labs(name = 'Forecast Runs', fill = 'buu') +
  # legend("test1","test2")
print(series_plot)
```

[image: Output of code below]

Comment: `facet_wrap(vars(variable), scales = "free_y")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You free one or both scales in the `facet_*` functions.

(**Update**: I think your recent comment suggests reshaping the data slightly ... scroll to the bottom for another way to look at it.)

Using your sample data, keep "x" the same but free "y":

```r
ggplot(data = final_df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = value_fcst_1), colour = 'dodgerblue2', na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = value_fcst_2), colour = 'coral2', na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(vars(variable), scales="free_y") +
  labs(x = 'Months') +
  labs(title = 'Comparisons of two different forecast runs', subtitle = '2019-05-31 vs 2019-06-30 forecast runs')
```

[image: y axis independent]

Free both "x" and "y":

```r
ggplot(data = final_df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = value_fcst_1), colour = 'dodgerblue2', na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = value_fcst_2), colour = 'coral2', na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(vars(variable), scales="free") +
  labs(x = 'Months') +
  labs(title = 'Comparisons of two different forecast runs', subtitle = '2019-05-31 vs 2019-06-30 forecast runs')
```

[image]

---

**Update**: the best way to "add a legend" based on when the forecast was run is to let `ggplot2` do it for you. And to do that, you need it ***in*** a variable, not ***as*** a variable. Right now, you have `value_fcst_1` *as* a variable, and `value_fcst_2` *as* a variable. Let's reshape the data. I'm using `dplyr` and `tidyr` here, though there are base and `data.table` methods as well.

```r
library(dplyr) # and tidyr is used
final_df %>%
  tidyr::gather(k, v, -month, -marketplace, -variable) %>%
  slice(1:3, n() - 0:2) # just to show some sampling
#        month marketplace variable            k        v
# 1 2019-05-26          US      GMS value_fcst_1  4202393
# 2 2019-06-02          US      GMS value_fcst_1 30504725
# 3 2019-06-09          US      GMS value_fcst_1 30454694
# 4 2019-06-30          UK      ALC value_fcst_2 31198360
# 5 2019-06-23          UK      ALC value_fcst_2 31682497
# 6 2019-06-16          UK      ALC value_fcst_2 30363117
```

This is putting the forecast run *in* a variable (named `k` here). From here, it's easy enough to do

```r
final_df %>%
  tidyr::gather(k, v, -month, -marketplace, -variable) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = v, color = k), na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(vars(variable), scales="free") +
  labs(x = 'Months') +
  labs(title = 'Comparisons of two different forecast runs', subtitle = '2019-05-31 vs 2019-06-30 forecast runs')
```

[image: legend options for "forecast run"]

The `k` is certainly ugly, but I kept it intentionally, as there are two easy fixes:

- use `tidyr::gather("Forecast Run", v, ...)`, though this requires `` `Forecast Run` `` (backticks!) as a variable name (due to the space); or
- add `scale_color_discrete(name = "Forecast Run")`, which has the benefit of using something "easier" like `k` (ok, perhaps single-letter variable names are too terse) everywhere but still allowing a good legend name.

Each has its benefits/advantages.

Comment: Thanks! How do I do this for every country in the dataset and how do I add legend so that the names are 'Forecast run on date_run' (see commented part of my initial code, this did not work)?

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. For *"every country in the dataset"*, this code should work with more than just two, what are you seeing? For the label, do you mean as a caption, as in `labs(caption="Forecast run today")`, or something else? (I may be misinterpreting your `date_run`.)

Comment: Blue line represents one forecast run (e.g. Jan 1st) and the red one represents another forecast run (Feb 1st). I want to label them on the RHS as 'Forecast run on date_1' and  'Forecast run on date_2'. Date_1 and date_2 are flexible. 

I tried `legend(xy.coords(x = month), legend = c("Line 1", "Line 2"))` but getting the error that `cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'`

Comment: `legend` is base graphics, not `ggplot2`, so will fail regardless. Similarly, `xy.coords` doesn't speak gg, unfortunately. I have a thought, stby for an edit ...